# Unable to activate analytic asset in satellite Imagery

Tags: python, raster, imagery, visualisation, digital-image-processing

I was trying to import the map of Melbourne. I was able to fetch the details from API coordinates but when i am trying to check the analytic asset status, it is returning inactive.

```
# extract image IDs only
image_ids = [feature['id'] for feature in search_result.json() . 
['features']]
print(image_ids)

# For demo purposes, just grab the first image ID
id0 = image_ids[0]
id0_url = 'https://api.planet.com/data/v1/item- 
types/{}/items/{}/assets'.format(item_type, id0)

# Returns JSON metadata for assets in this ID. Learn more: 
planet.com/docs/reference/data-api/items-assets/#asset
result = \
requests.get(
id0_url,
auth=('APIKEY', '')
)

# List of asset types available for this particular satellite image
print(result.json().keys())

# This is "inactive" if the "analytic" asset has not yet been 
activated; otherwise 'active'
print(result.json()['analytic_dn']['status'])
```

And That gives me:

```
['20180831_235330_1008', '20180831_000115_0f31']
dict_keys(['analytic', 'analytic_dn', 'analytic_dn_xml', 'analytic_sr', 
'analytic_xml', 'basic_analytic', 'basic_analytic_dn', 
'basic_analytic_dn_nitf', 'basic_analytic_dn_rpc', 
'basic_analytic_dn_rpc_nitf', 'basic_analytic_dn_xml', 
'basic_analytic_dn_xml_nitf', 'basic_analytic_nitf', 
'basic_analytic_rpc', 'basic_analytic_rpc_nitf', 'basic_analytic_xml', 
'basic_analytic_xml_nitf', 'basic_udm', 'basic_udm2', 'udm', 'udm2'])
inactive
```

The status is returning as inactive. It should be active.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Planet Explorer gui to confirm the status of your order? It may not have finished processing yet. I suggest using this tool for faster, more user friendly downloads https://github.com/samapriya/porder